# Can't burn Mac OS X 10.7 Lion to a disc because it doesn't have enough space

Tags: macos, dvd, dvd-burning

When I try to burn my downloaded Mac OS X 10.7 Lion install disc to a DVD, I get this error:

> The disc inserted does not have enough free space

The DMG disc image says it's "4.72 GB" and the physical label on the DVD says it's "4.7 GB". Disk Utility on Mac OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard, the installed OS, says the inserted DVD is 0 bytes.

There are guides available for how to burn Lion to a disc, so it must be possible, unless it isn't possible *anymore*?

Comment: Can you run us through how you're trying to burn the installer?

Comment: Perhaps the DVD is not empty? Have you tried another DVD? Please tell us what sort of Mac you are using, and the current macOS that it is running.

Comment: I downloaded it from the App Store, then copied the `InstallESD.dmg` file to the desktop, then dragged it into Disk Utility, then clicked "Burn".

Comment: So use a dual-layer DVD, which has enough space.  Not hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Mark Wilson mentioned in the comments, "use a dual-layer DVD."

A "standard" DVD only holds 4GB of data. Generally a little less than 4GB usually as the DVD's file system has a little overhead so it is usually 3.9GB or thereabouts.

Best Buy, Office Depot and Amazon all sell dual layer DVDs. Look for ones with 8.5GB capacity that say "DL"after the DVD-R or DVD+R on the packaging.