# 2006 iMac5,1 Upgrade from 10.6.8 to a faster OS

Tags: snow-leopard, upgrade

I have an iMac 2006 5,1 2.16GHz Core 2 Duo to which I have changed the RAM to 4gb.
I want to upgrade the OS of 10.6.8 to a better OS, not sure which system.
Ideally i would be able to watch films etc via Netflix or the like.  Run AutoCAD design drafting software and sketch up.
General admin/accounts for domestic use and simple Internet use.
I have linux on my laptop so don't have issues but the iMac is storage of music and photos of my wifes and she is very pro apple. So best to keep it to apple OS. i managed to get thru to apple support who thought i had the best OS for that machine. But i am hopeful that i can get lion onto it.

Comment: Are you willing to install a non-Apple operating system, such as Linux? What types of applications do you use on the computer? Knowing this will help answers focus on your needs.

Comment: You probably could install Windows 10. I say probably because Windows 10 is not officially supported on your model by Apple. You would have to try and install to find out. Although you do not have to pay for Windows 10 to try Windows 10, you do have to pay to continue to use Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

According to [EveryMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.16-17-inch-specs.html), the maximum OS X for that machine is 10.7.5 Lion, which is fine except that it is [not free](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion) and the web browsers for it are obsolete. Safari will frequently fail due to invalid certificates. The best browser you can get is [Firefox ESR 45.9.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/45.9.0/releasenotes/).

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329758/what-exactly-do-i-get-when-i-purchase-an-older-version-of-mac-os-x